# The method eth_syncing does not exist\/is not available

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, json-rpc

I am starting `geth` like the below command

`Geth "--ipcdisable --rpc --fast --datadir="path" --rpcapi personal"`

I want to get the `blockchain` synchronization details from geth.

So I issue the following command

`curl -x http://127.0.0.1:8545/ {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_syncing","params":[],"id":1}`

But I get this exception

`{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"error":{"code":-32601,"message":"The method eth_syncing does not exist\/is not available"}}`

I can see from the logs that `blockchain` is synchronizing but I cant run this command. How to fix this.

Comment: `--testnet --ipcdisable --rpc --fast --datadir="path" --rpcapi db,eth,net,web3,personal"` this did the trick for me. Its working now

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
user@Kumquat:~$ curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_syncing","params":[],"id":1}' http://localhost:8545
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":{"currentBlock":"0x1eb260","highestBlock":"0x1eb478","knownStates":"0x0","pulledStates":"0x0","startingBlock":"0x1eaea3"}}
```